# Django CMS user can't have permissions to add plugins

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-admin, django-cms

I've got a Django-CMS site where I created a Articles model to add news, events and other material. This model has a content field which is a PlaceholderField so users can add the plugins they want to each article. The problem is that I created a user without superuser status but give him all the permissions that appear when I create/edit users. But this user can't add plugins to this model. He can add plugins to cms pages, but not to this model. Do I need to create some kind of permission for this case? How do I do it?

My model:

```
class Articles(models.Model):

    objects = ArticlesManager()

    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)

    sites = models.ManyToManyField(Site, verbose_name=_(u'Show in Sites'), related_name='articles_to_show')

    type = models.ForeignKey('Types', db_column='TYPE_ID',
                             related_name='type', verbose_name=_(u'Type'))

    content = PlaceholderField('ipp_article_content',
                               related_name='IPP_ARTICLE_CONTENT')

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'cms_ipportalegre'
        db_table = 'ipp_articles'
        verbose_name = _(u'Article')
        verbose_name_plural = _(u'Articles')
        permissions = (
            ("view_articles", _(u"Can view Articles")),
        )
```

And in my template:

```
<p>{% render_placeholder object.content language placeholder_language %}</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I has in my admin.py a configuration for ArticleAdmin and ArticleAdminForm where I had defined the "content" in the exclude field.

```
class ArticleAdminForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Articles
        exclude = ["title", "description", "content" , "creation_date", "site", "slug", "counter"]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ArticleAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class ArticleAdmin(PlaceholderAdminMixin, FrontendEditableAdminMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ArticleAdminForm
    frontend_editable_fields = ("sites", "featured_image", "article_image", "title_pt", "title_en", "title_es", "title_fr")
```

When I removed the `content` from the `exclude` everything started to work fine.